# Oracle row column transpose

Tags: oracle

I have the data in the following tables in Oracle database

table1

```
t1_id 
1 
2
```

table2

```
t2_id   t2_text1    t2_text2 
1       text1       text2
1       text3       text4
2       text5       text6
2       text7       text8
```

I need the output in the following way

```
t1_id   t2_text1_1  t2_text1_2  t2_text2_1  t2_text2_1 
1       text1       text3       text2       text4 
2       text5       text7       text6       text8
```

Comment: I don't understand what logic did u apply to get such results from such data, care to explain? (In table 2 all t2_id are equal 1, so suggested result is not possible)

Comment: my bad..it is this way

Comment: table 2
t2_id  t2_text1 t2_text2
1       text1    text2
1       text3    text4
2       text5    text6
2       text7    text8

Comment: For every t2_id there can be only 2 rows

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.t1_id,
               t21.t2_text1 t2_text1_1,
               t22.t2_text1 t2_text1_2,
               t21.t2_text2 t2_text2_1,
               t22.t2_text2 t2_text2_2
          from table1 t1, table2 t21, table2 t22
         where t1.t1_id=t21.t2_id and t21.t2_id=t22.t2_id and t21.rowid < t22.rowid
```

Good luck! :)